# How to redirect to action in ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got two actions in my ASP.NET Core Web API application's controller:

```
[HttpGet("get-all")]
public IActionResult GetAll() { ... }
```

and

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ...

    return RedirectToAction("GetAll"); 
}
```

`Delete` action always redirects to itself and never to `GetAll`. Why so? In the same time similar redirect from `Post` action works ok.

Can't find any docs on the subject. Any help?

Comment: Why would you redirect in a web api?

Comment: You can make a request in Delete action to GetAll action by HttpClient's GetAsync method and return it's result.

Comment: @Brad, I just want to return updated collection to the client without issuing a new request to `GetAll`.

Comment: @Orhun, `RedirectToAction` method is meant to do the thing, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure that browsers even follow redirects on XHR requests.  Certainly not on Delete verb.

Comment: @Brad, so you think the only way is to copy-paste code from `GetAll` action into `Delete`? I thought there might be a DRY solution.

Comment: The DRY solution is for your delete action to return `NoContent()` and then let the client request `GetAll()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use RedirectToActionResult? Like this (change ControllerName with your actual Controller's name ):

```
RedirectToActionResult("GetAll", "ControllerName", null);
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttoactionresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RedirectToActionResult__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

Hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: You can Aldo try to RedirectToRoute("routeName", routeValues) where routeName can be Added to the http route as a name e.g. [HttpGet("get-all", Name = "routeName")]

Comment: What is the difference between ReDirectToAction & ReDirectToActionResult?